# Conditional Multivariate KDE has multiple maxima and minima

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, statsmodels, kernel-density

Below is a plot of the PDF, CDF and Log CDF of a Conditional Multivariate KDE using Statsmodel:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(30)
nobs = 100
c1 = np.random.normal(size=(nobs,1))
c2 = np.random.normal(2,1,size=(nobs,1))
c3 = np.random.normal(3,2,size=(nobs,1))


x = pd.DataFrame(c1, columns=['var1'])
y = pd.DataFrame(c2, columns=['var2'])
z = pd.DataFrame(c3, columns=['var3'])

data = pd.concat([x, y,z], axis=1)
data =data.sort_values('var1')
# Assume each row in the data corresponds to a point in the (x,y,z) plane.

kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEMultivariateConditional(endog=[data['var1']],exog=[data['var2'],data['var3']], dep_type='c', indep_type='cc', bw='cv_ml')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

#Edited as suggested by JohanC 
ax.plot(data['var1'], kde.pdf(endog_predict=[data['var1']],exog_predict=[data['var2'],data['var3']]), label='PDF')
ax.plot(data['var1'], kde.cdf(endog_predict=[data['var1']],exog_predict=[data['var2'],data['var3']]), label='CDF')
ax.plot(data['var1'], np.log(kde.pdf(endog_predict=[data['var1']],exog_predict=[data['var2'],data['var3']])), label='Log PDF')
ax.legend(loc = 'best')
ax.grid(True, zorder=-5)
```

The output is:
[image]

I am planning to segment the pdf but I have found out that there are multiple minima's and maxima's:

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
minima, maxima = argrelextrema(kde.pdf(endog_predict=[data['var1']],exog_predict=[data['var2'],data['var3']]), np.less)[0], argrelextrema(kde.pdf(endog_predict=[data['var1']],exog_predict=[data['var2'],data['var3']]), np.greater)[0]
print('minima')
print(minima)
print('maxima')
print(maxima)
```

output:

```
minima
[ 2  5  8 12 15 19 23 25 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 46 48 51 54 56 60 66 69 72
 76 78 81 83 89 91 94 98]
maxima
[ 3  7 10 14 17 22 24 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 45 47 50 53 55 58 62 67 70 74
 77 79 82 87 90 92 96]
```

For segmenting here is my code:

```
#segmentation part
a = [c1[c1 < minima[0]], c1[(c1 >= minima[0]) & (c1 <= minima[1])], c1[c1 >= minima[1]]]
#number of segments
print(len(a))
```

Can someone validate if my segmentation process is correct? Another question is should I use the PDF or the log(PDF) to find the cuts (local extrema).

Comment: As your `c1` is unordered, a line plot looks very chaotic. Maybe it's better to replace `ax.plot` by `ax.scatter`?

Comment: Thanks for raising this, I re-edited my question.

Comment: Your bandwidth seems to be too small.  It also looks like your data has some large gaps which creates challenges getting a single (non-local) bandwidth to work well.  You should try creating the smooth with different bandwidths.